# R hist right/left clump binning

Tags: r, histogram, bins

I have a data set of length 15,000 with real values from 0 to 100. My data set is HEAVILY skewed to the left. I'm trying to accomplish the following bins: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, >10. What i have done so far is created the following:

```
  breakvector = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100)
```

and have run:

```
  hist(datavector, breaks=breakvector, xlim=(0, 13))
```

However, it seems like this results in a histogram where data greater than 13 aren't included. Does anyone have any idea on how to get R to bin all the rest of the data in the last bin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have values over 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this

```
datavector<-c(sample(1:9, 40, replace=T), sample(10:100, 20, replace=T))
breakvector <- c(0:11)
hist(ifelse(datavector>10,11,datavector), breaks=breakvector, xlim=c(0, 13), xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:11-.5, labels=c(1:10, ">10"))
```

Rather than adjusting the breaks, i just throw all the values `>10` into a bin for 11. Then i update the axis accordingly.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. didn't know you could use an ifelse statement like that.